# patching android native SMS application

Tags: android, sms

I have been trying to create a plugin for android native SMS application. That is when installed will adds smiles to android application. Just like this application.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.handcent.smileys.android&feature=search_resultpplication

I have no idea from where to start. I just need to know by extending and implementing which classes will helps me to achieve this.

I need some beginning directions.

I know it is a noobish question but I am stuck with this and This is possible, a sample app is there on android market. Please check the link I showed to you.

regards,
Aqif

Answer (score 0):

> This is possible

No, it is not.

> Please check the link I showed to you.

Quoting the page you linked to, "This is stock android smileys plugin for Handcent SMS". Handcent SMS is an application distributed through the Android Market; the plugin you linked to is for that application and only that application.

You cannot create plugins for the "android native SMS application". You can create your own SMS client (as Handcent did), or you can create custom firmware that contains a modified version of the "android native SMS application".